# Why does this structure has the size of 100 bytes?

Tags: c, struct, padding, sizeof

I'm trying to understand how the padding bytes are allocated (in C programming language) in the following example and I can't understand. The size of the "STUDENT" structure is 100 bytes. In my attempts of adding the extra bytes I failed to reach 100, my closest being 104 and 88. I put in round brackets (for 104), respectively square brackets (for 88) the way I thought about the allocation method. If someone can explain how the padding bytes were allocated in the following example I would highly appreciate.

I have an x64-based processor and I used Visual Studio Code for compiling.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    typedef struct
    {
        int day, month, year;
    } DATE;

    typedef struct
    {
        char name[40];          // 40 bytes  
        DATE registration_date; // 12 bytes (+4 padding bytes) 
        int study_year;         // 4 bytes (+12 padding bytes) [+8 padding bytes]
        int group;              // 4 bytes (+12 padding bytes) [+8 padding bytes]
        int grades[10];         // 10 bytes (+6 padding bytes) [+2 padding bytes]

    } STUDENT;

    STUDENT student;
    printf("Bytes: %d\n", sizeof(student)); // 100
    printf("The adress of name: %d\n", &student.name[40]); // 6422244
    printf("The adress of registration_date: %d\n", &student.registration_date); // 6422244
    printf("The adress of study_year: %d\n", &student.study_year); // 6422256
    printf("The adress of group: %d\n", &student.group); // 6422260
    printf("The adress of grades: %d\n", &student.grades[10]); // 6422304
}
```

Comment: int grades[10] is 40 bytes, it's a int array of 10 elements.

Comment: There is no padding in this struct.

Comment: You can use [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) to inspect the layout.

Answer (score 4):

```
    typedef struct
    {
        char name[40];          // 40 bytes  
        DATE registration_date; // 12 bytes (no padding) 
        int study_year;         // 4 bytes (no padding)
        int group;              // 4 bytes (no padding)
        int grades[10];         // 40 bytes (no padding)
                        // TOTAL : 100 bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

I got 100 bytes. You counted 1 byte per int in `grades`. The struct wasn't padded because nothing demanded a higher alignment than 4 bytes.